# How to fix '_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bd"' error when using grid() on Tkinter Widgets in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create an array of Tkinter widgets. To do this, I want to run through a `for` loop and add dynamically named items to a dicitonary, then use `grid()` to put those items on the screen. However, on the line of code including `grid()`, I get the aforementioned `_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bd"` error message.

To my understanding, this error message is thrown when one of the parameter arguments passed through `grid()` is not acceptable. However, if you look at the problematic code, I don't think you'll find any erroneous parameters--certainly nothing resembling a `-bd`. The only parameters I included in `grid()` are `(app, row=i, column=1)`.

Here's some example code:

```py
def newFrame(count):

    v_eventCount = IntVar()
    v_eventCount.set(count)

    events = {}

    for i in range(1,v_eventCount.get()+1):

        stri = str(i)

        events['l_event'+stri+'Marker'] = Label(app, text="Event "+stri+":")
        events['l_event'+stri+'Marker'].grid(app, row=i, column=1)
```

I expect the result of this code to be the display of the dictionary item `events['l_event'+stri+'Marker']` at grid location (i,1). In other words, I want to see a Label that says "Event 1" at grid location (1,1) when i=1 ("Event 2" at (2,1) when i=2, and so on...). Instead, the widget is not displayed at all and the previously mentioned error message is thrown.

I don't know what to do. I'm very new to Tkinter and Python as a whole so please be nice! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `grid(app, row=i, column=1)` - what is `app` for?

Comment: @HenryYik app is the location to grid to, it's the name of my tkinter window. I'm fairly sure that's necessary but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @HenryYik I just removed `app` and ran it again. It gave me the same error message.

Comment: You need to specify the master when you create the widget, but not when you `pack`, `grid` or `place` the widget .

Answer (score 3):

it was a really simply syntax error. I wasn't supposed to include `app` in my grid() parameters. I still don't understand why the error mentioned `-bd` but at this point I don't really care.

Comment: Sometimes when one's brain gets stuck one cannot find the obvious error. I have been working with tkinter for years and today I made the same mistake. Thank you for this question and answer...