# Trying to make a simple entry widget but keep getting an error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just trying to make a very simple entry widget and grid it on the window but I keep getting an error. Anyway I can fix it?

code:

```
e = tk.Entry(root, borderwidth=5, width=35) 
e.grid(root, row=0,column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mosta\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 298, in <module>
    e.grid(root, row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)
  File "C:\Users\mosta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2522, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bd": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the argument `root` from the `grid` command.

```
e.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: Exactly. [The `.grid(...)` method](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/grid.html) does not take an argument like that. Just name/value options. See also [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57049483/666583) on a very similar question.

Answer (score -2):

By using the .place() method instead of the .grid() method, I have successfully gotten the Entry widget to work.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, borderwidth=5) 
e.place(x=10, y=10, height=25, width=180)
```

I hope that this helps :-)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem to help I tried doing it and I got the same error

Comment: What operating system are you using? I tried this solution on Windows using Python 3 in the Idle editor and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm using windows and doing it on pycharm